# Access OmniAuth helper in Sinatra view

Tags: ruby, sinatra, omniauth, erb

I'm new to this, so forgive me if I'm being stupid!

I'm using [OmniAuth for Sinatra](https://github.com/charliepark/omniauth-for-sinatra) to help authenticate users. In my `layout.erb`, I'd like to access the `current_user` helper to check if the user is logged in. The helper goes like this:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.get(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

But I'm not sure how to access it in my layout view. I thought this would do the trick:

```
<% if current_user %> Do stuff here <% end %>
```

But no luck. Any help would be appreciated! Like I said, I'm new to Ruby, and I'm not a strong developer.

Answer (score 1):

You [need to define that method inside `helpers` block](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#helpview), like this:

```
helpers do
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.get(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

Then it will be available to the view.